# getLocationInWindow includes status bar

Tags: android, tablet

I need to know the absolute coordinate of a view, especially Y.

Here I used,

```
Button myBtn;
...
int loc[] = new int[2];
myBtn.getLocationInWindow(loc);
```

loc[1] means Y coordinate, but includes status bar's height.

By the way, when I test with a device(Most android tablet) its status bar is on bottom, doesn't include status bar's height and successful.

The problem occurs on top status bar devices(Nexus 7, Galaxy Note 2014 edition).

Comment: The bar's height is included because you ask for its absolute location. Might be easier to manually subtract the status bar's height.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thank you. I can subtract status bar's height, but when status bar is on bottom, it is impossible. I hope to know where is the status bar.

Comment: You could retrieve the device model or something and if its a tablet (status bad on bottom) you dont have subtract the bar's height